# Variable not being set in Visual Studio Post-build event command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, visual-studio-2017

I have the following script in a Windows batch file that fetches the version of a DLL file and renames an existing file by inserting the version in its file name. This works fine when I put it in a .bat file and run it in Windows. The resultant file name is GCSv1.1.0.7316.zip.

```
SET WMICommand="WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name='E:\\Projects\\GCS\\bin\\Debug\\Client.dll' get Version /value"
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%x in ('%WMICommand%') do (set vers=%%x)
    echo %vers%
    echo GCS_v%vers%.zip
    ren E:\Projects\GCS\InstallerTemplateProject\DeployFolder\GCS_Package.zip GCS_v%vers%.zip
```

I need to take this same script and put it in a Post-build event command line in Visual Studio to rename the generated file as a last step in the build process. Which is as follows:

```
    SET WMICommand="WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name='$(SolutionDir)GCS\bin\debug\\Client.dll' get Version /value"
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%x in ("%WMICommand%") do (set vers=%%x)
ren "$(SolutionDir)GCS\InstallerTemplateProject\DeployFolder\GCS_Package.zip" GCS_v%vers%.zip
```

But for some reason, the renaming is not happening properly because it is being renamed to GCS_v.zip.
Clearly the %vers% variable is not being set when it is in the Post-build event command line. Why does it work when executing it in a .bat file on Windows, but not when executing in a post-build? What should I do differently to the variable here? The goal is to get the second batch working in visual Studio. The first batch I wrote it just to test it out.

Comment: I'm having this issue also.  I only have 1 BAT file and something simple like SET DIR=~dp0 followed by echo DIR is %DIR%  returns  DIR is  (null/blank)   Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Each of the batchfiles is invoked independently and instantiates its own environment, so the second batch does not acquire the changes made the the first's variables.

Two obvious solutions

Use `setx` to `set` the variable into the second batch (with the downside that it will *also* be included in the environment of any other batch started following the `setx`) - probably then use `setx` to clear the variable from the second batch.

Write the variable to a file and read the file back into the second batch.

---

Ah - my misinterpretation, caused by skimming. I'd assumed the first batch was a pre-build and the second a post-build.

The problem appears to be that VS is not substituting the *actual* (and no doubt per-project) value of `Solutiondir` into the batch - which it logically cannot do because there's no guarantee that `$(whatever)` isn't a string with another interpretation within a random batchfile.

I'd suggest that you try

```
set>afilename.txt
```

as the first command within the post-build batch, which will create a file containing the value of most of the environment variables. It may very well be that a variable named something like `solutiondir` is installed in the environment for the post-build batch - but I can't guarantee that...

Comment: I don't know if I explained clearly, but the first batch was written just to test my batch file. The goal is to only have the second batch run properly in Visual Sutio's post-build event command line. So I am not transferring variables from the first batch file to the second one. I will try out this setx.